# How can i remove a class from div using click events on specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, object

i have an issue i can't fix, so here comes my very first stackoverflow topic ! I am doing a member presentation page which shows only the members' picture and name, and when we click it, more informations pop in the div and the div grows in size using a class added with jquery to trigger an animation. So far, displaying the content works, but for a reason i don't find i can't close the member's div by removing its class. Here is the html, css and jquery. I'm also working on a ruby environment.

```
<div class="member">
<div class="profile">
  <!-- name and picture of the member -->
</div>

<!-- this div is hidden with css -->
<div class="member-presentation">
  <!-- content -->

  <!-- a close button to remove the .active-member class -->
  <button class="close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div> <!-- member-presentation -->
```

I use SASS to display hidden content when the right class is added.

```
.member {
   border: 0;
   width: 235px;
   transition: all 200ms ease-out;

   .member-presentation {
     display: none;
   }
}
.member.active-member {
    width: 800px;

   .member-presentation {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

And then comes the jquery, which is the part that won't work.

```
var $member = $('div.member');
var member = {
    showPresentation : function() {
        if(!$member.hasClass('active-member')) {
            $(this).addClass('active-member');
        }
        else if($member.hasClass('active-member')) {
            // this is to prevent closing the presentation by clicking anywhere on it
            $(this).preventDefault();
        }
    }, // attribute showPresentation

    closePresentation : function () {
        if($member.hasClass('active-member')) {
            $('.close').click(function () {
                $member.removeClass('active-member');
            });
        }

    } // attribute closePresentation
}; // object member

//execution of the functions
$member.on('click', member.showPresentation);
$member.on('click', member.closePresentation);
```

The class won't be removed on the click of the close button and i don't know how to make it work... I would also like to make it happen when we click outside of the member div or on a sibling member div that would inherit the .active-member class, but i have no idea how to do it... I am pretty new to jquery so maybe the solution is easy but i'm in despair ! Anybody who can help me will be my hero !

Comment: Seems to be a typo in your code, or maybe just in your post? You are missing the closing of the button (">").
<button class="close"<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

Comment: What is the need of `$('.close').click(function () {` ??

Comment: *********<button class="close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

Comment: Did you mean to put `event.preventDefault()`  instead of `$(this).preventDefault();`  ?

Comment: oops sorry it's a typo in the post, not in the code !
Bla... The need in the click event for the .close is to remove the .active-member class when we click on it.
mike510a what is the difference between the event and $(this) ? Sorry i'm not familiar with this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to close a div by clicking outside it or any of its siblings:

```
// Add click event for closing the div by clicking outside it
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!myDiv.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && myDiv.has(e.target).length === 0 ) { // ... nor a descendant of the container
        myDiv.hide();
        $(document).unbind( 'mouseup');
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm gonna try it, i keep you in touch fast, thank you !

Comment: for now it crashes, however i don't know if this comes from the code or if it comes from ruby, i will try in a simpler environment.

Comment: ok so I used your code on a basic environment without ruby and it works perfectly, it looks like the problem comes from ruby and not jquery, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could use this trick as well to perform the desired action:
by simply using the `on` and `off`  jQuery  functions  to  add/remove event listeners from whatever elements you so desire at the correct times by using a callback such as this one: `$("#member").show(function() {`
(see code below for example)

A Callback is essentially a function that is executed after a function is completed.  In my example below, if you were to read it in plain english it would essentially be something like this:

**EDIT**

When the 'show' link is clicked, hide the 'show' link, and make the 'member'  box visible.

Once the member box is visible, when any 'div'  element is clicked,

- hide the 'member' div
- make the 'show' link visible
- stop reacting to any div elements being clicked

```js
$("#show").on("click", function() { //add listener
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#member").show(function() { //callback

    $("div").on("click", function() { //callback

      $("#member").hide();
      $("#show").show();
      $("div").off("click");  //remove listener
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#member {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="show" href='javascript: void(0)'>Show</a>
<div id="member"> Member Presentation <br><br>
  <a id="close" href='javascript: void(0)'>Close</a></div>
```

:

Comment: that would work indeed, however it's important that the two parts are under the same div, it toggles hidden content when we click. However your code is inspiring i'll try some stuff based on your answer, thank you !